# How to modify weights of Keras layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to freeze some of the weights of a layer by setting them to a specific value in Keras. How can I achieve this without moving weights to CPU ?

I checked similar questions such as [modify layer weights in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539595/modify-layer-weights-in-keras) and [modify layer parameters in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810702/modify-layer-parameters-in-keras)

Answers suggest usage of `get_weights()` and 'set_weights()', however those functions moves weights between CPU and GPU.

I created a custom lambda layer and modified model.trainable_weights inside of that layer, however weights are not updated.

I used tf advanced tutorial, and just added a custom lambda layer that multiplies weights with zero. 
[Colab notebook with same code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t7mhictbbJj8Jumx3XY-1ndJIoge5mdQ)

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import Model

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# Add a channels dimension
x_train = x_train[..., tf.newaxis]
x_test = x_test[..., tf.newaxis]

def antirectifier(x):
    for i,w in enumerate(model.trainable_weights):
        model.trainable_weights[i] = tf.multiply(w,0)

    return x

class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    self.mask = Lambda(antirectifier)

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    x = self.mask(x)

    return self.d2(x)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='test_accuracy')

@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(images)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(labels, predictions)

@tf.function
def test_step(images, labels):
  predictions = model(images)
  t_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

  test_loss(t_loss)
  test_accuracy(labels, predictions)

EPOCHS = 5

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  for images, labels in train_ds:
    train_step(images, labels)

  for test_images, test_labels in test_ds:
    test_step(test_images, test_labels)

  template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}, Test Loss: {}, Test Accuracy: {}'
  print(template.format(epoch+1,
                        train_loss.result(),
                        train_accuracy.result()*100,
                        test_loss.result(),
                        test_accuracy.result()*100))

  # Reset the metrics for the next epoch
  train_loss.reset_states()
  train_accuracy.reset_states()
  test_loss.reset_states()
  test_accuracy.reset_states()
```

Since weights are zero, accuracy should be low. However weights are not changed.

Comment: Why do you not want your weights to be moved to CPU in the first place?

Comment: @NewEyes moving data between cpu and gpu slows down training significantly.